# != operator not working in while loop condition when combined with || OR

Tags: javascript

I have a basic do while loop where I am executing a prompt's input value, then running it through the condition. For some odd reason when I use !== along with || in the same condition it does not work. I know that I can add additional parameters for it to compare against using isNaN and other logical operators, but it makes no sense why this does not work and I would like to get this route working.

```
var number;
do {
    number = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1 or 2'));
}
while ((number !== 1) || (number !== 2));
```

If I were to run the following code with a single expression to compare against, it work no problem, but in the previous statement it does not like have multiple conditions to compare against.

```
var number;
do {
    number = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1 or 2'));
}
while (number !== 1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you checking for?  Making sure they entered either a 1 or a 2 but nothing else?  (Hunch is you need && not ||.)

Comment: The number will always not be 1 OR not be 2. You want to say that `number` is not 1 AND is not 2.

Comment: `!(number===1 || number===2)`, or `(number!==1 && number!==2)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"?  Assuming the given answer doesn't solve it for you.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks a lot the && statement worked. Totally makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number is 1, then the LHS is false but it isn't 2 so the RHS is true and the overall test is true.

If the number is not 1, then the LHS is true and the overall test is true.

You need `&&` there so you are saying *If the number is not 1 and it is also not 2*.

Answer (score 0):

starting with a do guaranteed at least 1 calculation.
in your case with 2 or comparison,  it should be an && operator.

guaranteed 1 calculation before testing for exit

```
var number;
do {
    number = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1 or 2'));
}
while ((number !== 1) && (number !== 2));
```

does not guaranteed

```
 var number;
    while ((number !== 1) && (number !== 2));
    {
        number = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1 or 2'));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick input!

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic problem and it's bound to give true in any case as it is.

```
var number;
do {
    number = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1 or 2'));
}
while ((number !== 1) || (number !== 2));

number = undefined;// or any other value !==1 AND !==2, then true
number = 1;// !==2 BUT ==1, then true
number = 2;// !==1 BUT ==2, then true
```

You need to check if both statements are `true` at once, and not one or the other.

```
var number;
do {
    number = parseInt(prompt('Enter 1 or 2'));
}
while ((number !== 1) && (number !== 2));

number = undefined;// or any other value !== 1 AND !== 2, then true
number = 1;// !== 2 BUT == 1, then false
number = 2;// !== 1 BUT == 2, then false
```